# Creating a derived array type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, prototype-programming, prototype-chain

I'd like to make my own JavaScript queue type based on JS Array. I'd like instances of my queue to be fully functional instances of JS arrays. I'd like for them to have some extra methods, starting with an enq (enqueue) and deq (dequeue) methods. My first attempt failed, for reasons I don't understand.

```
function makeQueue_attempt_1() {
  let prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
  prototype.enq = Array.prototype.shift;
  prototype.deq = Array.prototype.pop;
  return Object.create(prototype);
}
```

Question 1: why doesn't my implementation work? Is it even a good idea or should what I want to do be done by some other method?

Question 2: what would be a better approach?

Comment: What is not working with your current implementation? (keep in mind, `.shift()` removes an element from the start of an array, it doesn't add like `.unshift()`)

Comment: ["It's not working" is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: Oh, how utterly embarrassing. It seems the only problem is me confusing .shift() and .unshift(). Replacing .shift in my code above with .unshift makes it work the way I intended. I was sure it was something with prototypes or arrays I didn't understand. Many thanks @NickParsons !

Comment: NB: because you're creating a new Prototype object in each function call, if you use this factory method more than once you will be unable to compare via `instanceof` whether two such objects are actually of the same type.

Comment: Yes, I can see that now that you are pointing that out for me, I'll try to fix it. Many thanks @Alnitak

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class named `Queue` or whatever you want. There you can implement your functionalities.

```js
class Queue {
  constructor() {
      this.value = [];
  }

  enqueue(val) {
    this.value.push(val);
    return this;
  }
  
  dequeue() {
    this.value.shift();
    return this;
  }
  
  get() {
    return this.value;
  }
}

const queue = new Queue();
queue.enqueue(20)
  .enqueue(10)
  .enqueue(22);

console.log('after enqueued:', queue.get());

queue.dequeue();
console.log('after dequeued:', queue.get());
```

##### Explanation

1. Create a class named `Queue`
2. Inside the `constructor` function initialize a `this.value` with an empty array.
3. Create an `enqueue` method which will push the provided value at the beginning of the `value` and finally returns the instance of the class for chaining.
4. Create a `dequeue` method which will peek a value from the front/beginning of the `value` and also return the `this` instance.
5. Create a `get` method for fetching the queue's updated values.

Comment: "I'd like instances of my queue to be fully functional instances of JS arrays"

Comment: @Alnitak "__Question 2: what would be a better approach?__" I think prototyping of an array will not be a good idea.